# How can I calculate the angles between a polygons vertices?

Tags: matlab, plot

Due to my lack of MATLAB code knowledge, I was lost as to how I can calculate the angles between vertices of a random polygon.

Below I load and plot a polygon using the polyshape() function in which the x and y values are loaded from a txt file.

(loadpoly.m)

```
[filename,~] = uigetfile('*.txt', 'Load data from txt file');
if filename~=0
    X_Y_Val = dlmread(filename, ' ');
end
X = X_Y_Val(:,1);
Y = X_Y_Val(:,2);
polygon = polyshape(X, Y);
plot(polygon)
```

(Randompolygon.txt)

```
0.29218 0.17609
0.56518 0.27635
0.69555 0.16324
0.83819 0.49486
0.62653 0.63882
0.27684 0.49743
```

My goal is to calculate the angles shown with the red marker and suggestions that can help me going in the right direction.

[image: Angles I wish to calculate]

Comment: Do you know how to compute the angle between two vectors? Do you understand how the polygon is encoded by its vertices? Do you know that three consecutive vertices can be turned into two vectors with the origin in the middle on of the three vertices? I think that is all you need to know to solve this problem!

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1585914-how-can-i-calculate-the-angles-between-a-polygons-vertices